# Show multi ListView in one screen

Tags: android, listview

i have 2 ListView and each one get informations from a website databse....
everything is going fine, but what i want is to show the first listview then under it the second listview without setting a fixed height .. like the user should scrool to the end of first listview and then show the second listview without showing the scroller. here what I have done :

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/firstlist"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    </ListView>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/secondlist"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         >
     </ListView>
    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

but the screen is not showing both even if i keep scrolling, only one listview ( the first ) is show up ... unless i give them fixed height eg `android:layout_height="180dp"` any ideas ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have same issue before. Here are four solutions:

1.give the `android:layout_weight = "1"` for each listview so them can halve the screen.

2.put them in a tabview.

3.Merge two lists into one listview.

4.Use ExpandableListView

Comment: i think number 2 is the better solution. as long as i can't merge them or put them in ExpandableListView because each one have it own info..

Answer (score 0):

why dont you use `ExpandableListView`

[Example 1](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ExpandableListView.html)

[Example 2](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidListView/article.html#miscellaneous_expandablelistview)

[Example 3](http://www.coderzheaven.com/expandable-listview-android-simpleexpandablelistadapter-simple-example/)

Comment: No problems, it will handle this.

Comment: you're right, thanks very much , but i think i will go after tabview as i think it could give a nice interface..

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try this?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/listView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1" >
</ListView>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="5dp"
    android:background="#C0C0C0" >
</LinearLayout>

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/listView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1" >
</ListView>
```

Comment: well, i still have to scroll them, and both listview show up in the same screen from the half..