# Android Layout Overlap

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I was having trouble in layouts. I have `ExpandableListView` & `ListView` . when I view that fragment `ExpandableListView` will overlap above `ListView`(images)

I Wanted `ExpandableListView` should appear after `ListView`.

ScreenShot:

[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">
        <ListView
            android:minWidth="25px"
            android:minHeight="25px"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/climages" />
        <ExpandableListView
            android:id="@+id/catExpandableListview"
            android:minWidth="25px"
            android:minHeight="25px"
            android:groupIndicator="@android:color/transparent"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:indicatorRight="45sp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        <ProgressBar
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/homeProgress"
            android:layout_gravity="center" />
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
</FrameLayout>
```

Edited: Changed RelativeLayout to FrameLayout

Comment: try giving your layout a background color.Most preferably white or any other of your choice

Comment: @AnirudhSharma i want ExpandableListView should appear after listview..

Comment: try adding this line in your xml in expandable list view android:layout_below="@+id/climages"

Comment: @AnirudhSharma sorry i had to use FrameLayout.. no its not working. if i use RelativeLayout  -> overlaping on others pages. Still its not fixed yet

Comment: Try to add `android:layout_weight="0.5"` to your `ExpandableListView` and `ListView`

Comment: @Rami Nope :( not working.

Comment: I just tested it and it works, i'll post the code

Answer (score 0):

Try using the following layout instead of the above.I modified it and it gives the desired result

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <ListView
            android:minWidth="25px"
            android:minHeight="25px"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/climages" />
        <ExpandableListView
            android:id="@+id/catExpandableListview"
            android:minWidth="25px"
            android:minHeight="25px"
            android:groupIndicator="@android:color/transparent"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:indicatorRight="45sp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <ProgressBar
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/homeProgress"
        android:layout_gravity="center" />

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Comment: ExpandableListView is not visible. Seems its back of listview

Comment: @Raj i guess yoy expandable list view is visible.The problem might be that beacuse you are using two listviews in a single layout and your first view contains data large enough to hide the expandable list view.The expandable list view is just below your list view.But you are unable to scroll it as your whole layout is not scrollable.

Comment: @Raj try hiding your list view and then see if expandable list view is there or not

Comment: @Raj ok you can use weight to give equal height to your both list view as mentioned by Rami

Comment: @Raj or you can put your whole layout in a scroll view.Ex:-http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17693578/android-how-to-display-2-listviews-in-one-activity-one-after-the-other

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `android:layout_weight` :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent">

                <LinearLayout 
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:orientation="vertical">
                    <ListView
                        android:minWidth="25px"
                        android:minHeight="25px"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="0dp"
                        android:id="@+id/climages"
                        android:layout_weight="0.5" />
                    <ExpandableListView
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="0dp" 
                        android:id="@+id/catExpandableListview"
                        android:minWidth="25px"
                        android:minHeight="25px"
                        android:groupIndicator="@android:color/transparent"
                        android:indicatorRight="45sp"
                        android:layout_weight="0.5"/>
              </LinearLayout>

              <ProgressBar
                  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                  android:id="@+id/homeProgress"
                  android:layout_gravity="center" />
          </RelativeLayout>
     </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: I don't want to give them equal height. i just want ExpandableListView below listview

Comment: I don't think it's possible to do it like that, you'll always have the overlap problem. Maybe as workaround you can put your two lists inside a ScrollView and update their height every remove/add of an item. Notice that the use of two scrollable views inside each other is not recommended