# make layout above listview scroll - android

Tags: java, android, android-layout, listview, android-listview

I have a list view (with sticky headers), and then a relative layout above it. And I want the relative layout to scroll before the listview does.

I tried putting a scroll view as the parent of the whole thing but this doesnt work, becuase I am using sticky headers, and then they lose functionality.

How could I scroll the relative layout out of the way before the list view. **Without going into a lot of detail, I cannot just make the relative layout the listview header**

Thanks for the help :)

Comment: I recommend using StickyListHeaders: https://github.com/emilsjolander/StickyListHeaders

Comment: put your listview in a Fragment.. and put all in a ScrollView

Comment: @james, Can you please refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17693578/android-how-to-display-2-listviews-in-one-activity-one-after-the-other/28713754#28713754 link ? I did for two listview, now you have to take your relative layout.