# Two listview in a ScrollView. One list view with cursorloader and one with static data

Tags: android, listview, scrollview

I need to put one listview with cursorloader above and down one litsview with static data. This is my layout

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:fillViewport="true" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="10dip"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/header_mi_facultad"
        android:text="@string/header_list_mi_facultad"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:minHeight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textSize="22sp"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:background="#336699"
        />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    </ListView>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/header_textview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:minHeight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
        android:text="@string/header_list_servicios"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textSize="22sp"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:background="#336699"
        />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list_servicios"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:entries="@array/servicios_array"
        >
    </ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

the snippet of the fragment where i set the adapters

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "---Se creo la vista del MainActivityFragment---");

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_main, container, false);
    ListView listView = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.list_view);

    listServiciosView = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.list_servicios);
    serviciosAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), R.layout.list_item, servicios);
    listServiciosView.setAdapter(serviciosAdapter);

    menuAdapter = new MenuAdapter(getActivity(), null, 0);
    listView.setAdapter(menuAdapter);

    ListUtils.setDynamicHeight(listView);
    ListUtils.setDynamicHeight(listServiciosView);

    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

            Cursor cursor = (Cursor) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
            int index = cursor.getColumnIndex(AppContract.MenuEntry.COLUMN_TYPE);
            int type = cursor.getInt(index);
            Intent intent;
            Log.d(LOG_TAG, "id : " + id + " position : " + position);
            Log.d(LOG_TAG, "tipo : " + type);

            switch (type) {
                case NOTICIA_LISTA:
                    index = cursor.getColumnIndex(AppContract.MenuEntry._ID);
                    Long idMenu = cursor.getLong(index);
                    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "url : " + idMenu);
                    intent = new Intent(view.getContext(), ListActivity.class);
                    intent.putExtra("idSolicitado", idMenu);
                    intent.putExtra("idOrigen", 0);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    break;
                case NOTICIA_URL:
                    index = cursor.getColumnIndex(AppContract.MenuEntry.COLUMN_URL);
                    String url = cursor.getString(index);
                    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "url : " + url);
                    intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                    intent.setData(Uri.parse(url));
                    startActivity(intent);
                    break;
                case SERVICIO_CUOTA:
                    intent = new Intent(view.getContext(), PayActivity.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    break;
                default:
                    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Nada!!!");
                    break;
            }
        }
    });

    listServiciosView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

            Intent intent;
            Log.d(LOG_TAG, "id : " + id + " position : " + position);

            switch (position) {
                case 0:
                    intent = new Intent(view.getContext(), PayActivity.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    break;
                default:
                    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Nada!!!");
                    break;
            }
        }
    });

    return rootView;
}
```

the utility class that i tried

```
public static class ListUtils {
    public static void setDynamicHeight(ListView mListView) {
        ListAdapter mListAdapter = mListView.getAdapter();
        if (mListAdapter == null) {
            // when adapter is null
            return;
        }
        int height = 0;
        int desiredWidth = View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(mListView.getWidth(), View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);
        for (int i = 0; i < mListAdapter.getCount(); i++) {
            View listItem = mListAdapter.getView(i, null, mListView);
            listItem.measure(desiredWidth, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);
            height += listItem.getMeasuredHeight();
        }
        ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = mListView.getLayoutParams();
        params.height = height + (mListView.getDividerHeight() * (mListAdapter.getCount() - 1));
        mListView.setLayoutParams(params);
        mListView.requestLayout();
    }
}
```

Here are the screenshots url
[sc1](https://www.dropbox.com/s/jxi4kwazcqxbjye/Aj3hIZFYpzFtEDcigpq22To7gwXsOpfjwcxTnwYFmCT7.jpg?dl=0)
[sc2](https://www.dropbox.com/s/me3rfvniru0vbjp/AqE7wO_yHCDYFSglEn77WXK-T95h0N2dY-NVt0AWJnYr.jpg?dl=0)
it works with portrait orientation, but with landscape the firts listview only show the firts element. I want to show all the elements in it. How i can do that? I tried this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17693578/android-how-to-display-2-listviews-in-one-activity-one-after-the-other) and it works with static data but in my case have the problem explained. Is there a problem with the cursor loader? or i miss something in the layout?

Comment: `Two listview in a ScrollView.` that's not a good start. It is usually not recommended to use a listview in a scrollview, let alone 2.

Answer (score 0):

are you saving all your variable sate using SaveInstanceState method.