# How to display two listview in one xaml file one after other in Xamarin .forms?

Tags: android, xaml, listview, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have four different listview which is getting data from four different data source.Each listview, I have created separate which is consuming separate RESTful api.I want to display all the listview in one xaml page one after another like notification in facebook. Link for reference - [Android how to display 2 listviews in one activity one after the other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17693578/android-how-to-display-2-listviews-in-one-activity-one-after-the-other).
I want to create in Xamarin.forms

Comment: simply place multiple ListViews within a Layout container

Answer (score 2):

Not sure what you need, but seems like you want to display at least 4 different data types in a single ListView. It can be done with `DataTemplateSelector`.

> A DataTemplateSelector can be used to choose a DataTemplate at runtime
>   based on the value of a data-bound property. This enables multiple
>   DataTemplates to be applied to the same type of object in order to
>   customize the appearance of select objects.

Examples and details are available [here](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/application-fundamentals/templates/data-templates/selector/).

P.S.: Having multiple ListViews on the same page, especially four of them, may indicate a UX smell. But, if you still want to have multiple ListView on the same page, it is doable:

```
<ContentPage>
   <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical">
      <ListView ItemsSource="{Bindind Source1}" />
      <ListView ItemsSource="{Bindind Source2}" />
      <ListView ItemsSource="{Bindind Source3}" />
      <ListView ItemsSource="{Bindind Source4}" />
   </StackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```