# Xamarin Forms How to display 2 listviews in one page?

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.forms.listview

I want to display two listviews in one page like this
[image: 2 listViews in one Page]

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/a/43190597/1970317

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Having a ListView inside a ScrollView is not supported an will leak memory, you can use a single ListView but with different [DataTemplate](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/application-fundamentals/templates/data-templates/creating/) with a [DataTemplateSelector](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/application-fundamentals/templates/data-templates/selector/) and organize your Data.

What I can tell is that in your case you don't need a ListView since there are not a lot of items, maybe using a Grid + ScrollView will get you the job done!

Answer (score -1):

Use [Layouts](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/user-interface/controls/layouts/) to arrange multiple controls on a page.  The simplest approach would be with a StackLayout, but you could also use a Grid or any of the other Layout controls.

```
StackLayout stack = new StackLayout();

stack.Children.Add(myFirstList);
stack.Children.Add(mySecondList);
```

Comment: But screen is small and atacklayout doesn't scroll

Comment: then add a ScrollView

Comment: Images with scrollview

Comment: Having a ListView in a ScrollView is not supported