# Multiple RecyclerView not working in same Fragment

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, fragment, android-adapter

I have two `RecyclerView` in my `Fragment`.

```
 <LinearLayout                  
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="match_parent" 
             android:orientation="vertical"
             android:background="#E6E6E6">  
<RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
      <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textview"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textColor="#000"
        android:paddingBottom="8dp"
        android:paddingTop="8dp"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:text="Trending"
        />
    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:scrollbars="none"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textview"
   />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/popular_textview"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textColor="#000"
        android:paddingBottom="8dp"
        android:paddingTop="8dp"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:text="Popular"
        android:layout_below="@+id/recycler_view"
        android:layout_marginTop="200dip"
        />
    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/popular_recycler_view"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:scrollbars="none" 
    android:layout_below="@+id/popular_textview"/> 
 </RelativeLayout>
```

But it's only first `RecyclerView` is working . second one is not visible .
My `Fragment` code is like this :

```
private void populatRecyclerView(ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> imageList) {

    ArrayList<Data_Model> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < imageList.size(); i++) {
        HashMap<String, String> vector = imageList.get(i);
        category = vector.get("deal_category");
        if (category.equalsIgnoreCase("17")) {
            String imageurl = vector.get("deal_thumbnail");
            String title = vector.get("title");
            Uri uri = Uri.parse(imageurl);
            String filename = uri.getLastPathSegment();
            arrayList.add(new Data_Model(title, filename));
            RecyclerView_Adapter adapter = new RecyclerView_Adapter(getActivity(), arrayList);
            recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);// first set adapter on recyclerview
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();// Notify the adapter
        } else {
            String imageurl = vector.get("deal_thumbnail");
            String title = vector.get("title");
            Uri uri = Uri.parse(imageurl);
            String filename = uri.getLastPathSegment();
            arrayList.add(new Data_Model(title, filename));

            RecyclerView_Popular_Adapter popular_adapter = new RecyclerView_Popular_Adapter(getActivity(), arrayList);
            popular_recyclerView.setAdapter(popular_adapter);// second set adapter on recyclerview
            popular_adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();// Notify the adapter
        }
    }
}
```

Even second `TextView` is also not appearing.I have specified first and second adapter in comment. So how make second `RecyclerView` visible too?

Comment: since you have specified condition only one will be visible in a single instance (which means your if(true) always)

Comment: for some cases it goes in else loop . I have cross checked that one.

Comment: try to fix the height of the Recyclerview.if you are populating the recyclerview conditionally why do you need two of them?

Comment: first one is auto scroller and second one is not auto scroller .so i need two different recyclerview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use `layout_weight` on childs of `RelativeLayout` . Your parent views should be under the `LinearLayout` like below;

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textview"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:paddingBottom="8dp"
            android:paddingTop="8dp"
            android:text="Trending"
            android:textColor="#000"
            android:textSize="20sp" />

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/textview"
            android:scrollbars="none" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/popular_textview"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:paddingBottom="8dp"
            android:paddingTop="8dp"
            android:text="Popular"
            android:textColor="#000"
            android:textSize="20sp" />

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/popular_recycler_view"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/popular_textview"
            android:scrollbars="none" />

    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

[image]

Hope it helps!

Comment: Yeah i tried by removing layout_weight still its not working.

Comment: its not enough, you should seperate your RecylerViews by group and set layout_weight for this groups parent.

Comment: One more problem I am facing now . This view is not scrollable .I tried using <scrollview> but still not working. Can u help me please ?

Comment: If it works, you should approve and complete this post. For one more problem, you should look this post;  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16515879/multiple-listviews-inside-a-scrollview

Comment: This link solution is not working for me .I have posted seperate question for scroll.